# difference between generic function with "where" and simple function with the same classes

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core

I read the book Hands-On Design Patterns with C# and .NET Core by Gaurav Aroraa (Author) and Jeffrey Chilberto (Author)

I saw that example:

```
public static class PetFeeder
{
 public static void FeedPet<TP, TF>(TP pet, TF food) where TP : PetAnimal
 where TF : IpetFood
 {
 pet.Feed(food);
 }
}
```

but why I can`t write just

```
public static class PetFeeder
{
 public static void FeedPet(PetAnimal pet, IpetFood food)
 {
 pet.Feed(food);
 }
}
```

so my question is why do we need to describe parameters with "where" when we can just specify those classes and avoid using a generic function

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one benefit at least. There may be more, but this comes to mind right away.

Without generics, if you `return` the objects that you put into the method, then the returned objects are typed using the fixed type that the method declares. They are not typed with the actual type that they might have. You'll need to take additional effort in checking the returned type and casting if applicable.

Example:

```
public static class PetFeeder
{
  public static PetAnimal FeedPet(PetAnimal pet, IpetFood food)
  {
    pet.Feed(food);
    return pet;   // <-- We now RETURN the pet object
  }
}
```

The return value of `FeedPet(myAnimal, myFood)` is now always of type `PetAnimal`, even if you use a `PetSnake` object as a parameter. If you want to use the result as a `PetSnake` (e.g. because it has a method or property that `PetAnimal` does not have) then you first need to cast it to `PetSnake`.

The same is true for the interface type: interfaces may also have inherited interface types, with the highest one (`IFood`) typically having fewer properties or methods compared to their descendant interface types, which would also need casting to access those again.

So this does not need casting of the returned `pet` object:

```
public static class PetFeeder
{
  public static T FeedPet<T>(T pet, IpetFood food) where T: PetAnimal
  {
    pet.Feed(food);
    return pet;   // <-- We RETURN the pet object, using its actual type T
  }
}
```